# ¿Cómo agregar valores con PouchDB find?

Tags: pouchdb

Estoy leyendo sobre el plugin '[find](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find)' para [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/). Parece muy flexible y útil, pero no veo como agregar valores con eso. ¿Es posible agregar valores con PouchDB-find, o lo tengo que hacer manualmente?

Answer (score -1):

`pouchdb-find` es un plug-in y proporciona un avanzado *lenguaje de consultas* para `PouchDB`.

Como tal, solo dispone de métodos para búsqueda y manejo de índices, está inspirado en el *lenguaje de consultas* de `MongoDB` y logra lo mismo que `map/reduce` sólo que con menos código.

Para cualquier operación básica deberás usar la API normal de PouchDB.

Comment: Para mi, el punto de usar PouchDB-find es para evitar usar el API normal, porque el API normal requiere el uso de `eval`, que es contra la policia de seguridad de mi aplicación.  Pero puedo agregar manualmente.

Comment: Quien quiera que haya votado negativo, estaría bien saber por qué. Sólo así se puede corregir un problema.